# How do I troubleshoot a zfs dataset that the server when the server can't agree if it's mounted or not?

Tags: linux, zfs

I have a ZFS dataset that exists in `/proc/mounts` and in `/etc/mtab`, but the folder doesn't exist in the filesystem, `zfs umount` reports the dataset doesn't exist, and `zfs mount` reports that the dataset is already mounted.

This is on RHEL 8.8 (fully updated) running zfs dkms 2.1.11-1

Is it possible to umount this dataset without rebooting the server? How would I even begin to troubleshoot this sort of problem?

I believe this occurred when it had the sharenfs setting enabled on the dataset and then a `zfs umount` was attempted while the nfs daemon was sharing. I have tried setting `sharenfs=off` (which succeeds, but doesn't fix the problem). The nfs services have been shut down and the problem still occurs. I can `zfs send` the datasets to another system and verify they're intact, but I just need them mounted on *this* server.

I am not using containers or additional mount namespaces (that I'm aware of).

The mounts are listed in `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/mounts`

```
topher@nzxt:/$ grep Backups -H /etc/mtab /proc/mounts
/etc/mtab:array/Backups /array/Backups zfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,xattr,noacl 0 0
/etc/mtab:array/Backups/gwen /array/Backups/gwen zfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,xattr,noacl 0 0
/proc/mounts:array/Backups /array/Backups zfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,xattr,noacl 0 0
/proc/mounts:array/Backups/gwen /array/Backups/gwen zfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,xattr,noacl 0 0
```

The directory doesn't exist in the filesystem

```
topher@nzxt:/$ ls /array/Backups
ls: cannot access '/array/Backups': No such file or directory
```

The dataset do exist in zfs (pool is `array`)

```
topher@nzxt:/$ zfs list array/Backups array/Backups/gwen
NAME                 USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
array/Backups       2.62T  1.59T     1.71T  /array/Backups
array/Backups/gwen   364G  1.59T      364G  /array/Backups/gwen
```

Umounting (lazy, forced, or otherwise) fails.

```
topher@nzxt:/$ sudo zfs umount array/Backups
cannot unmount '/array/Backups/gwen': no such pool or dataset

topher@nzxt:/$ sudo zfs umount array/Backups/gwen
cannot unmount '/array/Backups/gwen': no such pool or dataset

topher@nzxt:/$ sudo umount /array/Backups/gwen
umount: /array/Backups/gwen: no mount point specified.

topher@nzxt:/$ sudo umount /array/Backups
umount: /array/Backups: no mount point specified.
```

I'm unable to export the zfs pool either.

```
topher@nzxt:~$ sudo zpool export array
cannot unmount '/array/Backups/gwen': unmount failed
```

Attempts to remount the directory report that it's already mounted

```
topher@nzxt:/$ sudo zfs mount array/Backups
cannot mount 'array/Backups': filesystem already mounted

topher@nzxt:/$ sudo zfs mount array/Backups/gwen
cannot mount 'array/Backups/gwen': filesystem already mounted
```

`lsof` throws errors attempting to walk the affected directory and does not return any open filehandles in those paths

```
topher@nzxt:/$ sudo lsof | grep Backups
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() zfs file system /array/Backups
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() zfs file system /array/Backups/gwen
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

`fuser` doesn't think the mount exists

```
topher@nzxt:~$ sudo fuser -vm /array/Backups
Specified filename /array/Backups does not exist.
topher@nzxt:~$ sudo fuser -vm /array/Backups/gwen
Specified filename /array/Backups/gwen does not exist.
```

Comment: Can you export the zpool?  Or are there are other, still-mounted, filesystems on it that you need to leave mounted?

Comment: Yes, there are other datasets in use. Let me see if I can move those services elsewhere to test exporting.

Comment: Export fails with umount error. :/ Updating question.

Comment: What happens if you try to *mount* the filesystem?  If it succeeds, can you then unmount it successfully?

Comment: Attempts to mount say that it's already mounted... D:

Comment: Have you tried the `zfs mount ...` or `zfs unmount ...` commands?

Answer (score 3):

Try a lazy or forced `umount` and see what happens?

`umount -l` or `umount -f`

See: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/2435 and [Linux mountpoint can not be unmounted no matter what?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1055894/linux-mountpoint-can-not-be-unmounted-no-matter-what)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that neither of these worked. I'll amend my question.

Comment: Can you just reboot?

Comment: If there are stale handles, what does `showmount` or `netstat -anp | grep 2049` show?

Comment: samba and nfsd are off, nothing listening on those ports. showmount predictably times out after a minute with the message `clnt_create: RPC: Timed out` 

I might be able to reboot, but this is a production server, I'd like to know how to troubleshoot this issue (so that I can prevent/fix it) as rebooting is not always convenient. I suspect the mount is busy, but I don't know how to find out what is keeping open file handles and/or why zfs and the kernel can't agree on the current state.

Comment: Sometimes it's not worth troubleshooting... This is not a normal condition, so efforts to prevent it may not be fruitful. You can examine `zpool history` and `zpool events` for your own records. But take the downtime hit if this is important.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thank you. This is the second time this has happened (different dataset, different pool, but same server), I'm trying to figure out what I screwed up or if this is a bug I should report upstream. Guess I'm off to the mailing lists!